# migration: SMF to IPB

Tags: migration, forum

Is there a way to migrate from SMF to IPB (Simple Machines Forum to Invision PowerBoard, wich are forum systems). I've googled the question and found no answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It seems IPB staff has some free tools to convert from various other forum systems to their own.

http://communityseo.com/forums/SMF-IPB-t891.html